# Cordova InAppBrowser, going back to the first tab causes it to be refreshed

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser, iab

I'm dealing with an issue regarding the use of `InAppBrowser` in Cordova, and I hope someone can give me a hand in solving it.

Currently, I'm developing an app that utilizes `InAppBrowser` with the `_blank` option to open an external website and handle communication via `postMessage`. However, I also need to open an internal page (not a website) located in the `www` directory. To do this, I open a second instance of `InAppBrowser`.

The problem arises when the user navigates back from the second instance of `InAppBrowser` to the first one: the first instance reloads, forcing the user to wait for the `InAppBrowser` to load again. This is an undesired behavior, and I would like to find a solution to keep the first instance active without reloading.

I've searched everywhere but haven't found a satisfactory solution. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help!

I've tried everything

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.